# Animating Sketch' Generated SVG using CSS3

Tags: css, animation, svg

I have the following SVG code for an exported asset from a Sketch file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="116px" height="117px" viewBox="0 0 116 117" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="loader_circles">
    <!-- Generator: Sketch 47.1 (45422) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
    <title>Group 2</title>
    <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
    <defs>
        <circle id="path-1" cx="58.5" cy="58.5" r="58.5"></circle>

        <mask id="mask-2" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0" y="0" width="117" height="117" fill="white">
            <use xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
        </mask>

        <circle id="path-3" cx="59" cy="59" r="36"></circle>

        <mask id="mask-4" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0" y="0" width="72" height="72" fill="white">
            <use xlink:href="#path-3"></use>
        </mask>
    </defs>
    <g id="Common-elements" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-dasharray="78,34">
        <g id="Group-2" stroke="#4A90E2" stroke-width="14">
            <use  id="Oval-8" mask="url(#mask-2)" xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
            <use id="Oval-8" mask="url(#mask-4)" xlink:href="#path-3"></use>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

It is a loading spinner with two circles one inside of another, now my aim is to use CSS3 Keyframe animation to animate the two circles, mainly rotate it using `transform` property.

I am not an expert with SVG so I searched for ways to animate SVG with CSS and found that it is simply animating the elements inside of the SVG code for a particular path.

So I did this

```
#path-1 {
  transform-origin: center;
  animation: rotateClockwise 0.6s infinite linear;
}

#path-3 {
  transform-origin: center;
  animation: rotateAntiClockwise 0.6s infinite linear;
}


@keyframes rotateClockwise {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotateAntiClockwise {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

The animation works, the two circles spins as it should but somehow the circles just gets malformed, the strokes of the circles just gets paler and thicker. The spinner looks like this when I don't do the `transform`ation, I think the issue is mainly with the `transform` property

[image]

Here's a live demo:
http://jsbin.com/zipecefune

I am not sure why its happening, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is the source of the problem, but it seems wrong to animate something within `defs` as these are references, [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/defs):

> SVG allows graphical objects to be defined for later reuse. It is
>   recommended that, wherever possible, referenced elements be defined
>   inside of a `<defs>` element. Objects created inside a `<defs>` element
>   are not rendered immediately; instead, think of them as templates or
>   macros created for future use.

If instead of animating your `circle` elements you animate `use`, the problem is fixed (you need to rename the `id` property because they must be unique.

http://jsbin.com/qonokufimo/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Didn't know much about SVG and had no idea what was going on, thanks for pointing out the issue.